# Line-clamp works unexpectedly

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make `line-clamp` work. I use Tailwind CSS (unfortunately). As I did many times before I added utility class `line-clamp-2` (I need to show only 2 lines of the text). As you can see ellipsis appeared but on the third line we see the other part of the text. Could someone help me, please?
There is the mark up of that dropdown. Screenshot is attached either.

```
  <ul class="max-w-md rounded-xl bg-white py-2 text-sm shadow-2xl">
    <li
      class="my-0.5 px-3 py-2 font-medium line-clamp-2"
    >
      {{ currentUserAlias }}
    </li>
    <li v-for="(profileMenuItem, index) in items" :key="index" class="my-0.5">
      <Component
        :is="'a'"
        class="block whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-2 font-normal hover:bg-primary-100"
        :to="profileMenuItem.href"
        :href="getAbsoluteLink(profileMenuItem.href)"
      >
        {{ profileMenuItem.title }}
      </Component>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Part of the text on the next line showed because of `py-2` (padding will change element height). `line-clamp-{n}` utility adds dots at the end of `n` line but it does **NOT** magically removes text from the DOM (you may inspect it in a browser) - that is why it also adds `overflow: hidden;` property

In order to fix it, add inner wrapper for your text and put `line-clamp-2` on it

```html
<ul class="max-w-md rounded-xl bg-white py-2 text-sm shadow-2xl">
    <li
      class="my-0.5 px-3 py-2 font-medium"
    >
      <div class="line-clamp-2">
        {{ currentUserAlias }}
      </div>
    </li>
    
    // that part is irrelevant
  </ul>
```

Now no matter what outer padding is you will have [two](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MqbVKJr40C) clamped lines

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! Didn't know about that wrapper thing though used `line-clamp` many times before.